# Convention for main arguments

Tags: c++, conventions

Out of the constraints of a coding IDE, I've always written my main function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

But in IDEs where they start you off with a hello world type application structure to start you off, I've seen it written in different ways.  For example in Xcode, it has argv as a constant:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
```

I've also seen people declare argv[] as a double pointer, which I can't understand the reason to:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Is there any standard or convention to how this is declared?  Should I have a double pointer, or a constant?

Bonus question: should the asterisk denoting a pointer be placed just after the data type, just before the variable name or separated in the middle?

Comment: That last one I think is supposed to be char **argv without the brackets.

Comment: The double pointer version usually is `char** argv`, which is equivalent to `char* argv[]`

Comment: And the asterisk position doesn't matter, though it technically belongs to the variable, e.g. if you declare int *a, b; you'd have a as a pointer to an int, and b as an int.

Comment: The C99 standard (not directly relevant since it is a C++ question, but sometimes informative) specifies in §5.1.2.2.1: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
_or equivalent_, with a footnote indicating what the 'or equivalent' means: _Thus, `int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`, or the type of `argv` can be written as
`char ** argv`, and so on._  The C++ standard rules for `main` are stricter than the C rules for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there any standard or convention to how this is declared? Should I have a double pointer, or a constant?**

This is clearly defined in the C++ Standard.

Reference:
**C++03 Section § 3.6.1:**

**Para 2:**

> It shall have a return type of int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main:

```
int main() { /* … */ }

and 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* … */ }
```

> In the latter form argc shall be the number of arguments passed to the program from the environment in which the program is run. If argc is nonzero these arguments shall be supplied inargv[0] through argv[argc-1] as pointers to the initial characters of null-terminated multibyte strings (NTMBSs) (17.3.2.1.3.2) and argv[0] shall be the pointer to the initial character of a NTMBS that represents the name used to invoke the program or "". The value of argc shall be nonnegative. The value of argv[argc] shall be 0. [Note: it is recommended that any further (optional) parameters be added after argv]

Comment: could you include a link to that, please?

Comment: Thanks, what's the source for further reference?

Comment: @DavidEnglund: It is from the C++ standard copy, You can find similar quote in the draft copies of the standard available freely on the ISO website.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the various standards say that argv is NOT const.  Now, if your application isn't modifying argv, there's no reason you can't declare it const.

Comment: In C the `argv` parameter is guaranteed to be modifiable; interestingly the C++11 standard (draft) doesn't talk about this at all.